# How connect socket.io to php file?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I trying to connect to php type file with socket.io because I want to use php and socket.io in my site but if I try this (see code below).
When I enter to localhost:3000 a file called download is automatically downloading..

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var server = require("http").createServer(app);
var io = require("socket.io").listen(server);

users = [];
connections = [];

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
console.log("Server running...")

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.php");
});

io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket)
{
    connections.push(socket);
    console.log("Connected: %s sockets connected.", connections.length);

    //Disconnect
    socket.on("disconnect", function(data)
    {
        connections.splice(connections.indexOf(socket), 1);
        console.log("Disconnected: %s sockets connected.", 
        connections.length);
    });
});
```

I really need help because I don't know what I'm doing wrong...
I want php to build the login/users system and socket.io to have websokets in my site to make stuff.

I know php must use some kind of server like (XAMPP) but it's not helping when when I turn on XAMPP.

Comment: Socket.io or express can't run PHP code, you need a separate PHP capable webserver like apache to do that. That will mean you will be connecting to your PHP app in a different port

Answer (score 1):

PHP should run on a web server (with its own internal sockets), while socket.io creates a socket implementation itself.

So regular PHP files should run on the web server (and serve your website login/register/...) and if you want to write something on a socket.io generated socket with PHP, then you must somehow connect your PHP side to the node app.

There are many ways to make that connection. One way is to create a messaging system with Redis. PHP can post messages to the shared buffer in redis and the nodejs server would constantly pull messages and dispatch them via socket.io.

Check this library: https://github.com/rase-/socket.io-php-emitter

You may also completely move the socket logic to nodejs side so that it may not require any PHP intervention.

Comment: Ok, but can I connect the php with webscoket?

Comment: You can connect to the socket.io server via another socket in PHP but that would not be an efficient way if you are broadcasting lots of messages to so many people. Take a look at this simple example: https://github.com/psinetron/PHP_SocketIO_Client

Comment: I saw this tutorial - https://github.com/jdutheil/nodePHP But I have an error that IO in the nodeClient is not defind...

Comment: You can open an issue on git. It must be some missing require statement or a typo.